# Questions about the composition of two dominant rational maps.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading the [lecture notes](http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~malab/PDFs/Algebraic%20Geometry%20L3.pdf). On page 4, I have some difficulty in understanding the proof of the fact that $g \circ f$ exists for two dominant rational maps $f, g$.

[image]

Let $f: V \to W$ and $g: W \to U$ be dominant rational maps. It is said that "if we pick any point $Q \in W$ and any open set $S$ containing $Q$, then $S$ will also contain an element of $f(\operatorname{dom} f)$. Using the fact that rational maps are continuous we get that $f^{-1}(\operatorname{dom} g) \subset \operatorname{dom} f$ is a dense open set for any rational map $g : W \to U$, so $g \circ f$ is defined on a dense open set".

My questions are

(1) Why $S$ will also contain an element of $f(\operatorname{dom} f)$?

(2) Why $f^{-1}(\operatorname{dom} g) \subset \operatorname{dom} f$ and why $f^{-1}(\operatorname{dom} g)$ is a dense open subset of $V$?

(3) If $f$ is dominant but $g$ is not dominant, does $g \circ f$ always exist?

I think that since $f(\operatorname{dom} f)$ is dense in $W$, $$\overline{f(\operatorname{dom} f)} = \bigcap_{f(\operatorname{dom} f) \subseteq M, M \text{ is closed}} M = W. $$

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer point 1, suppose that $S$ contained no points in $f({\rm dom} f)$. Then $W\backslash S$ is closed, and contains $f({\rm dom} f)$. Thus the closure of $f({\rm dom} f)$ is contained in $W\backslash S$, and cannot be equal to $W$, contradicting it being dense.

Comment: thank you very much. It seems that "$W\backslash S$ is closed, and contains $S$" should be "$W\backslash S$ is closed, and contains $f(\operatorname{dom} f)$".

Comment: @LJR indeed, it should be, thank you